# Can no longer upload to flickr.com

Tags: photos, flickr, upload, photo-sharing

I've been using the flickr.com online photo service since like forever, and I've always uploaded plenty of photos and videos. On one of my accounts I've been uploading photos yesterday.

It worked at first, and I was able to upload like 30 Gigabytes of new photos, until I ran into upload timeout errors. The upload always failed at a 600 MB MOV video, I clicked retry at least 10 times, and always it started to upload again and failed at about 75%. Since I had always experienced problems with files bigger than 100 MB on flickr, I deleted that file and told the uploader to move on. But it failed at several ~50MB MOV video files as well (again, clicked retry several times to no avail), and as I removed them, it even failed at my regular, ~10MB JPEG photos.

The images seem to upload correctly, as my bandwidth meter and the progress wheel in the uploader show, but when the upload of a file is complete, the wheel disappears and the timeout error is displayed.

What I've tried so far:

- Logged out and back in to my account
- Restarted Firefox (which clears browsing data on quit)
- Tried Opera and Internet Explorer on Windows
- Tried Opera and Firefox on my Arch Linux machine
- Tried Safari and Firefox on my iMac
- Tried both wired and wireless connections
- Tried another network (cellular data) than my home network
- Tried another flickr.com account
- Tried uploading of ~100KB PNG screenshots

I don't know what's the issue, since it can't be the browser, it can't be the OS, it can't be the network, and it can't be the flickr account. Is flickr's server faulty?

Furthermore, I've noticed that when clicking the profile icon, flickr says I'm using 22% of my 1TB storage, but the bar indicating the usage is just filled blue by less than 1%. When the uploading worked yesterday, that bar was working as well.

Any ideas are very appreciated, since I really need that flickr account. Is anyone else having trouble?

Comment: It seems to work again, I didn't change anything. Maybe it was really some weird kind of server bug at flickr's side. If it happens again, I'll post again, but hopefully it'll work from now.